# MSSQL - Two tables with more than one relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

[image]

Given a product, my intention is to be able to create a conversion table that will serve as a lookup when converting from one unit of measure (*FromUomId*) to another (*ToUomId*). Both IDs can be found in the **UoM** table.

The conversion values will be supplied by the user, and will be stored in the *FromUnit* and *ToUnit* fields respectivley. For instance given a source UoM of *Kilos* and a target UoM of *Grams* the *FromUnit* field will contain 1 and *ToUnit* field will contain 1000.

However, while it make sense to me, I find the relationship to be odd in that there are two relationships that exist between **Conversion** and **UoM** tables.

My question is, is it acceptable to have this kind of multiple relationship?

Comment: Technically, there should be no problem with that, but note, that you will have to join UoM twice when querying. `Select * from Conversion c, UoM u1, UoM u2 where c.FromUomId=u1.UomId and c.ToUomId=u2.UomId`

Comment: Yes, it's fine. You might want to consider placing a constraint on `Conversion` such that if you have a given conversion for `a` to `b`, that you don't *also* store a conversion from `b` to `a` (unless your UOM conversions are in some way lossy)

Comment: @ronald, nice question, It has become an [exercise](http://uf.ctrl-alt-d.net/material/mostra/124/disseny-base-de-dades-es-possible-dues-interrelacions-entre-dues-entitats) for my students. I hope students don't hate you too much. Regards ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers is **yes** it is acceptable and this is the right way to do it.

When you write joins remember to assign **alias** to `UoM` table:

```
Select *
from Conversion C
inner join UoM as UoMfrom on UoMfrom.UomId = c.FromUomId
inner join UoM as UoMto on UoMto.UomId = c.FromUomId
```

Notice than, because `UoM` table appears for twice in sentence, you *must* assign a different alias for each occurrence.